# Spring and Hibernate: Multiple connections, thread safe

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, thread-safety

I have an existing Project working fine, but now I have to implement a Backup System that is executed exery day and dumps the Database to a File. I want to solve this using a `ScheduledTask`, but this means that there is another `Thread` using Hibernate.

**My Question:** How exactly can I make Hibernate Thread safe?

I have the following code-(snippets):

In applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="myEmf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="redb.main.core.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Management -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

So I can get the `EntityManager` by

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

But if i understood it correctly, every `Thread` needs its own `EntityManager` from the `EntityManagerFactory`.

How can I create a new `EntityManager` in an other class?

I have no `persistence.xml`. Do I have to create it?

Comment: Spring will inject a thread bound `EntityManger` (as explained in the documentation). Just make sure that what you do is inside a transaction, that way there will be a thread bound `EntityManager`. You don't get a single one each thread has its own (for the duration of a transaction or the request if you use an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter/-Interceptor` but that doesn't apply here because you want to us background threads.). However isn't it easier to let the database do the backup instead of trying to externalize it?

Comment: If the transaction doesn't start (and assuming you have `@Transactional`) make sure that you have a `<tx:annotation-driven />` to enable transactions. Also make sure you aren't duplicating bean instances, having a `component-scan` in your `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` might lead (depending on the setup) duplicate beans where one is proxied and has transactions and the other doesn't. In the filter there shouldn't be a transaction (yet) as that executes before everything else, the filter doesn't start a transaction but binds an `EntityManager` to the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

He-he. Welcome in the hell.

The main problem, that spring tries to do that with an aspect-based solution. Although this is buggy (or undebuggable), in trivial cases it can work.

The general answer to your question is that the `EntityManagerFactory` *can be* a global, static object in your software, although I were stoned if I simply used that.

By default, the spring aop "weaves" your application on deployment, finds all of the database entity classes by their annotations, and wraps their methods to provide always an existing entitymanager. This is the theory. But it is not the practice.

The practice is that you have very little control over what exactly will happen.

What I did: there is a servlet filter named `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`, which can open an entitymanager for every request, and flush/close that on need. Yes, its name is about "views", but soon its name is its first bug: practically we had to call it as "requesttransactionfilter" or such. It hasn't anything with the MVC views to do, it is working on the http request entities coming from your servlet container.

If you don't like to use servlet filters in a spring application, there is a also a spring interceptor named `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` with the very similar functionality, too.

Programmatically, you can generate an `EntityManager` from an `EntityManagerFactory` by its `createEntityManager()` method.

Happy googling! You are on the begin of a long way.

Comment: Spring ensure that you have a thread safe `EntityManager` it is just a proxy which looks up a thread bound `EntityManager` or creates a new one using the `EntityManagerFactory`. There is nothing scary about that and heck it works in countless enterprise applications around the globe. There is no weaving involved nor is there AspectJ involved. The Only AOP part is that you need to make sure that everything executes inside a transaction and it works. It isn't a long way it is just a matter of getting your configuration right and from what you describe you haven't and tried to work around it.

Comment: The `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` has indeed nothing to do with views but with requests and handling threads. But for background threads it doesn't do a thing. It is a `HandlerInterceptor` and part of Spring MVC and as such tied to the web. It is useless for background threads.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay. Giving misleading names to classes is a minor or a serious problem in case of a library? If something simply doesn't work (f.e., the tipical problem: transaction / EntityManager wasn't somehow created), how the hell can you dig out what _had_ _to_ _be_ _done_? The paradigm of local responsibility simply doesn't exist in the spring/aop. I am digging the spring source since months, and created a hird of questions about there which weren't simply answered. Yes, because there is none. The true answer for the unpleasant spring/aop question is: "dig into the source deeply and pray".

Comment: There is some truth in this response. If Spring creates a repository for you and you then hand that out to an unrelated Thread that has nothing to do with Spring, you are in trouble. It is not a good idea to do that. But I did. And what finally worked for me was removing all @Transactional annotations, switching to manual transactions (TransactionTemplate) AND, important, synchonizing [Java synchronize()] on each TransactionTemplate.